# Xna Monogame C# Keyborad input issue with German keyboard

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, xna, monogame

I would like to program a text input with xna, everything works, only the German letters "ö, ä, ü" are not recognized and there is no enum for these keys on the keyboard. When I enter it, the key "Keys.None" comes out. How can I check the entry of these keys?

I dont want to use another framework, so is there a way to check the input with xna monogame keyboard class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282004/how-to-properly-convert-keys-of-digits-to-string-in-mongame/72296082#72296082